# Elementor. How to make it use protractor.conf?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I started adding e2e tests into our project and it seems a few things changed since the last time I used Protractor. For example [elementExplorer](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-protractor-interactive) still useful, but [Elementor](https://github.com/andresdominguez/elementor) is way more cooler.

In its the readme is says to launch it by running e.g.: `webmanager start` and then `elementor http://localhost:3000`.

But this way it ignores protractor.conf. And since I have a binary path for Chrome browser in that file, along with a logic for clearing cookies and logging into the app in `onPrepare` function, protractor has to know where the file is. But I can't find a way.

Starting protractor as usual via `protractor protractor.conf.coffee` and then `elementor localhost:3000` not working either. It says "Unable to start a WebDriver session"

Comment: Good question!  I just started using Elementor myself, and I am wishing I could make it log-in for me.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you should launch it by running `webdriver-manager start`, I use this to run the scripts: `protractor script_file_conf.js` since I save my scripts as javascript code in my repository. Remember that the conf file should have a reference to the script file.

Comment: I don't get it. What are you saying? I have to run webdriver, protractor and elementor?

Comment: I don't think this answer pertains to Elementor at all, it just describes how to run Protractor.